# Complex Analysis: evaluating a definite integral using contour integration

Tags: complex-analysis

When I am evaluating the definite integral
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos x-e^{-x}}{x}dx$$
using contour integration, I find a conclusion
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}e^{iRe^{i\theta}}d\theta\to0$$
as $R\to\infty$ that needs to be applied. But I'm still confused about how it makes sense, and is there another way to figure out the original definite integral?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you do not need Complex Analysis. Since the Laplace transform is a self-adjoint operator,
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}\,dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty}(\mathcal{L} f)(s)\,ds $$
which in our case leads to
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos x-e^{-x}}{x}\,dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{s}{s^2+1}-\frac{1}{s+1}\right)\,ds=\lim_{s\to +\infty}\log\frac{\sqrt{s^2+1}}{s+1}=\color{red}{0}. $$

Comment: That’s quite surprising!

Comment: Sadly it is an assignment of Complex Analysis, in light of this I have to use contour integration. Actually it's natural to figure it out using Laplace transfom and this is where my conclusion comes from.